# "specified cast is not valid" using excel via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, c#-4.0, oledbconnection

I want to open and read data from a corrupted excel using C# console application. I was trying with this code:

```
 public System.Data.DataTable EXc(string path, string savedFile)
        {
            try
            {
                Missing missing = Missing.Value;
               Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile);
                workbook.Close(true, missing, missing);
                if (workbook != null)
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(savedFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
                        missing, missing, missing, missing,
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, missing,
                        missing, missing, missing, missing);

            }
```

But I'm getting the exception

> specified cast is not valid

In line

```
workbook.SaveAs(savedFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
                            missing, missing, missing, missing,
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, missing,
                            missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace? You're not casting anything, so it looks like it's happening further down.

Comment: @JamesJenkinson: Exception is being caught on this line

Comment: I mean down as in within the method calls. Post your stack trace.

Comment: If you are using C# 4 (and a sufficiently recent version of the interop assemblies), you can use named and optional parameters rather than spamming `missing` everywhere, to make code like this more readable. That is, `Workbooks.Open(path, CorruptLoad: XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert:I changed it, what is the advantage of using this code:Workbooks.Open(path, CorruptLoad: XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile),other than readability?

Comment: You say that as if readability isn't one of the most important things in code (and also writability, no fun counting those parameters)... but if your question is if there is any *functional* difference, then no. It's "merely" easier to maintain.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: sorry, I  asked about functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognized my mistake:

I was trying to save a closed workbook, may be because of that I got that exception

> Specified cast is not valid

After opening the corrupted excel using interop,we can use an oledb connection and copy that data into a datatable or dataset and can be used.

public System.Data.DataTable CorruptedExcel(string path, string savedFile)
        {

```
        try
        {
            Missing missing = Missing.Value;
           Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path, CorruptLoad: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile);

            var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            //var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {

                conn.Open();

                var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);



                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("ReadingExcel: Excel file could not be read! Check filepath.\n"
                + e.Message + e.StackTrace);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

may not have been the exact same issue, but I have gone to hell and back with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook and I found that the fix to not use the C:\ drive on my AWS windows system but the D:\ drive.  Something about the how the C: drive was mounted was breaking the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook SaveAs2 function call.  I tried a lot of other common fixes found online but this was the only thing that worked.